# No such file or directory on a simple shell command on GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I have the following job

```
  deploy-binary:
    needs: checkout-project
    runs-on: some-debian-machine
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}
    steps:
    - name: test current working directory
      run: pwd
```

Why does it fail with the following error?

```
Run pwd
Error: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on your self-hosted machine?

Comment: This problem occurs because you need to use the [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout) **in each job**, to be able to use the `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}` variable. To share it between jobs you would probably have to use outputs as a workaround.